# code structure of ISR with WDT?

Tags: watchdog, isr

where should the `Watchdog` reset be in embedded code with an Interrupt service routine?

in the main loop, or in the Interrupt service section?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your architecture and the requirement.

Generally, watchdog timer is a kind of hardware that is part of the micro-controller or processor which is configured via software with a timeout value. If the processor goes for a hang or some deadlock condition is met, and it does not recover within the timeout value configured for watchdog, the processor will be reset. So, the watchdog timer hardware will be linked with processor reset signal. You can also check this by having a corresponding debug log/breakpoint in the reset vector for watchdog reset.

Also, note that in some architecture watchdog timer can have a separate interrupt vector and hence there might be a separate wdt/special vector for it which performs only a selective level of reset rather than complete reset of hardware.

So, the WDT usage depends the architecture and requirement.

In some architectures, the WDT can be with low priority in background. Incase if you cannot run in background then you might need to explicitly trigger for certain unexpected conditions apart from other earlier mentioned scenarios like deadlock/hang. So, running as a separate thread / isr / invocation from main depends on your architecture and requirement.